# Python: Extending Selenium WebElement class

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I use Selenium I access HTML elements with an `S()` function so that I get a syntax that's simpler and more like jQuery:

```
def S(input, t=10):
    return Wait(driver, t).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, input)))
```

Using this you get:

```
S('button').click()
```

But Selenium lacks a lot of the jQuery functions like `.parent()`, `.val()` and so on.

The `.parent()` function can be polyfilled by simply calling `.find_element_by_xpath('..')`.

So my plan is to create a new class that inherits from the `WebElement` class by doing something like this:

```
class WebElement2(WebElement):

    def parent(self):
        return self.find_element_by_xpath('..')
```

However, this will only solve the first step because after creating that  replacement class I have to replace the series of functions and classes that trace back to:

`Wait(driver, t).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, input)))`

So can anyone help me understand the route that this takes? Will it be possible to do what I'm looking for? Can this be done by creating new classes and inheriting from the existing ones?

I've looked at the Selenium files and what I've worked out so far is:

```
expected_conditions.py
- class presence_of_element_located
- def _find_element

webdriver.py
- def find_element
- def execute
```

`presence_of_element_located` calls `_find_element`, which calls `find_element`, which calls `execute`, and then I can't work out what it does after that.

P.S. I know that creating a `.parent()` function will clash with the the existing `.parent()` function that does something else. The existing one can be renamed because it only gets used internally by Selenium.